# pl sql запрос (суммирование значений)

Tags: sql, алгоритм, oracle

Написал такой запрос:

```
select distinct tl. packno, tc.id, tc.name as atmnumb, tl.amount, sum(tah.inccash) as amountin, sum(tah.deccash) as amountout, ta.account as atmacc, 
DECODE(ta.currency, 840, 'USD', 398, 'KZT') as valuta, to_char (tl.time, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as incdate, to_char (tl.time, 'hh24:mi.ss')  as inctime, tl.termname, tl.type, tl.trancode
from TABLE_YSTROISTVA tc, TABLE_LOG tl, TABLE_CASSETS_1 tah, TABLE_ACC ta 
where tc.type=1 and tc.class=1 and tc.id=tl.origid and tl.id=tah.id and ta.id=tc.id and tah.deccash != '0.000'
and trunc(tl.time) = trunc(sysdate-1) 
and tl.trancode in (91,98) and tl.packno between
           to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) - 1, 'YY') || to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) - 1, 'MM') ||
                     to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) - 1, 'DD') || '001') and
           to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) + 1, 'YY') || to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) + 1, 'MM') ||
                     to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) + 1, 'DD') || '005') and tl.type = 999 and tc.class=tl.termclass
group by tl.termname, tc.id, tl.amount, tc.name, tl.termdate, tl.type, tl.packno, tl.time, tl.trancode, tah.inccash, tah.deccash, ta.account, ta.currency
UNION
select distinct tl. packno, tc.id, tc.name as atmnumb, tl.amount, sum(tah.inccash) as amountin, sum(tah.deccash) as amountout, ta.account as atmacc, 
DECODE(ta.currency, 840, 'USD', 398, 'KZT') as valuta, to_char (tl.time, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as incdate, to_char (tl.time, 'hh24:mi.ss')  as inctime, tl.termname, tl.type, tl.trancode
from TABLE_YSTROISTVA tc, TABLE_LOG tl, TABLE_CASSETS_2 tah, TABLE_ACC ta
where tc.type=1 and tc.class=1 and tc.id=tl.origid and tl.id=tah.id and ta.id=tc.id and tah.deccash != '0.000'
and trunc(tl.time) = trunc(sysdate-1)  
and tl.trancode in (91,98) and tl.packno between
           to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) - 1, 'YY') || to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) - 1, 'MM') ||
                     to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) - 1, 'DD') || '001') and
           to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) + 1, 'YY') || to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) + 1, 'MM') ||
                     to_char(trunc(sysdate-1) + 1, 'DD') || '005') and tl.type = 999 and tc.class=tl.termclass
group by tl.termname, tc.id, tl.amount, tc.name, tl.termdate, tl.type, tl.packno, tl.time, tl.trancode, tah.inccash, tah.deccash, ta.account, ta.currency
```

Результат такой:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v2lp.jpg

А должно выйти так:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCMjl.jpg

Смысл в том, что в полученном результате у меня с таблиц (TABLE_CASSETS_1/TABLE_CASSETS_2) берутся значения (tah.inccash, tah.deccash) и я не могу их корректно суммировать по причине того, что в некоторых устройствах присутствуют 2 валюты и значение дублируются при выводе и счетов устрйоств (таблица TABLE_ACC). Сумма по валютам должна быть раздельна, а также не должны выводиться куча счетов устройств. как в примере [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCMjl.jpg.

В примере [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v2lp.jpg мультивалютное устройство - это АТМ 700029.
В примере [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCMjl.jpg. мультивалютное устройство - это АТМ 700062.

Извиняюсь, не совсем правильно привел второй (нужный) результат. Запрос должен вывести следующее:3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1SMF.jpg

То есть в корректном исходном файле поля Сумма загрузки и Сумма разгрузки есть результаты сложения полей из файла 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCMjl.jpg, только без дублирующих значений в соответствующих полях. А также поле # счета АТМ не повторяется для АТМ 700027 и АТМ 700029

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопросе минимальный пример кода, данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Добавил доп описание запроса и корректный ожидаемый результат в самом запросе

Comment: Все данные, код, результаты выполнения, должны быть приведены в текстовом виде, не картинками.

Comment: Мои таблицы содержат много полей, тут средствами таблиц весьма неудобно выкладывать данные в виде таблицы.  Если есть возможность выложить картинку, почему нельзя использовать эту опцию?  Или можно как файл в формате *xls, * xlsx прикрепить (но такой опции не нашел)?

Comment: *Мои таблицы содержат много полей* и что - все они просто необходимы именно для демонстрации/воспроизведения проблемы? тогда сделайте адекватную модель. Вы пришли за помощью, а не за окончательным решением.

Comment: _Если есть возможность выложить картинку, почему нельзя использовать эту опцию?_, можно, почему нельзя. Но если вы в ответе заинтересованны, то так делать не надо. С картинок нельзя копировать. Вы наверное думаете, что таблицы TABLE_YSTROISTVA, TABLE_LOG, TABLE_CASSETS_1, TABLE_ACC есть на ноуте любого уважающего себя разработчика, но это не так.

Comment: Спасибо, понял суть исходных и конечных данных. Но, чем все это выкладывать, кажется легче подумать над алгоритмом самому :)

Comment: Выкладывать можно, например, на [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=baac74f6b0d6bf2c1c7b67a1677a68fa). Создавайте таблицы с данными, сокращяйте запрос, пока не будет достигнут уровень,  минимального примера, в котором ваша задача будет видна, понятна и воспроизводима. Если вы считаете, что проще будет самому решить,  чем проделать  эту работу, то зачем вы задали вопрос? За вас эту работу никто не сможет сделать.